# Unitialized values with ZeroMQ

Tags: c, valgrind, zeromq

I try to get the single parts of a 0mq message and it works like expected. 
Yet, if I test the programm with valgrind, I get:

> ==9436== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>
> ==9436==    at 0x4C2E128: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==9436==    by 0x401023: main (werft.c:73)
>
> ==9436==
>
> ==9436== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>
> ==9436==    at 0x4C2E128: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==9436==    by 0x401048: main (werft.c:74)
>
> ==9436==
>
> ==9436== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>
> ==9436==    at 0x4C2E128: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==9436==    by 0x538B7F9: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.25.so)
>
> ==9436==    by 0x53B246F: vsnprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.25.so)
>
> ==9436==    by 0x5391F5E: snprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.25.so)
>
> ==9436==    by 0x40106F: main (werft.c:74)

My code is:

```
#define DEVICE_IDENTITY "de.logicway.pferdepflug" 


int main()
{


    char *incoming[2];

    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();

    void *responder = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_ROUTER);
    zmq_bind(responder, "tcp://127.0.0.1:9990");


    void *requester = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_DEALER);
    zmq_setsockopt(requester, ZMQ_IDENTITY, DEVICE_IDENTITY, strlen(DEVICE_IDENTITY));
    zmq_connect(requester, "tcp://127.0.0.1:9990");

    zmq_send(requester, "testfahrt", 9, 0);

    zmq_msg_t received;
    zmq_msg_init(&received);

    int i = 0;
    do {      


        int size = zmq_msg_recv(&received, responder, 0);
        char *buffer = (char*) zmq_msg_data(&received);
        incoming[i] = (char*) malloc(strlen(buffer) +1 * sizeof(char*));
        snprintf(incoming[i], strlen(buffer) +1, "%s", buffer);

        i++;

    } while(zmq_msg_more(&received));


    printf("Identifier: %s\n", incoming[0]);
    printf("Message: %s\n", incoming[1]);    

    free(incoming[0]);
    free(incoming[1]);

    zmq_msg_close(&received);
    zmq_close(requester);
    zmq_close(responder);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
    return 0; 
}
```

(This will not go into production like it is, it's just for me to understand 0mq)

Since the code works "fine" as it is, the unitialized value might be no problem. But still, it bothers me.

**Question/s:**

- Should it bother me in this case? (Yes, I know, it always should normally ;) )
- And is the source of all that trouble in the zmq_msg_t received; /
  zmq_msg_init(&received); part?
- If not, where is it and how to fix it?

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: `strlen(buffer) +1 * sizeof(char*)` is equal to `strlen(buffer) +(1 * sizeof(char*))`, I suppose you mean `(strlen(buffer) +1) * sizeof(char*)`? Not that it matters since `strlen(buffer) + 1` should be enough.

Comment: Also, what line is line 73? And what happens if you have more than two messages? What happens if you only have *one* message?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you. Is there a rule of thumb when to use sizeof and when it is unnecessary?

Comment: Only time it's not needed is when getting the size of `char` (not `char*`). `sizeof(char)` is specified to *always* be `1`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Line 73 is the malloc for incoming[i]. Since this is a code just to understand there will be always two messages. The moment I use it in a "working code" I'll change that.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but instead of `malloc` and `snprintf`, all C implementations I know of come with a `strdup` functions which internally does `malloc` and `strcpy`. So doing just `incoming[i] = strdup(buffer);` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

### **Part 1:**

Valgrind mentions `strlen` is using uninitialized memory. In your case the parameter is `buffer` which was retrieved from zmq library.

Maybe you should check the return values from the involved function calls.

EDIT: I took the wrong API function. Removed this part.

---

### **Part 2:**

As already mentioned you also messed up your allocation a bit:

```
incoming[i] = (char*) malloc(strlen(buffer) +1 * sizeof(char*));
```

You don't need elements of type `char *` but only `char`. And the `+1` belongs to the length:

```
incoming[i] = (char*) malloc((strlen(buffer) +1) * sizeof(char));
```

Given the fact that `sizeof (char)` is defined to be 1 and the rule not to cast return value of `malloc`, we get this:

```
incoming[i] = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
```

The next step is copying the string from `buffer`:

```
snprintf(incoming[i], strlen(buffer) +1, "%s", buffer);
```

Given the fact that you just allocated sufficient memory (you might add a `NULL` check) there is not much benefit from using `snprintf`.
You could just use `strcpy` or simply create a copy with `strdup` in one step

Comment: I use zmq_msg_recv, not zmq_recv. The parameters are indeed different in these functions.

int zmq_msg_recv (zmq_msg_t *msg, void *socket, int flags);

Comment: You are right. I slipped to the wrong function in the API I've removed that part from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is ZeroMQ bug. I've got this output with `--track-origins=yes` valgrind option:

```
[ ~]$ valgrind --track-origins=yes ./a.out 
==5272== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5272== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5272== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5272== Command: ./a.out
==5272== 
==5272== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5272==    at 0x4C30BC8: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:454)
==5272==    by 0x400C52: main (111.c:31)
==5272==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==5272==    at 0x4E860B0: zmq::stream_engine_t::mechanism_ready() (stream_engine.cpp:793)
==5272== 
==5272== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5272==    at 0x4C30BC8: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:454)
==5272==    by 0x400C77: main (111.c:32)
==5272==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==5272==    at 0x4E860B0: zmq::stream_engine_t::mechanism_ready() (stream_engine.cpp:793)
==5272== 
==5272== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5272==    at 0x4C30BC8: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:454)
==5272==    by 0x50FAAD0: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==5272==    by 0x5123488: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:114)
==5272==    by 0x51017B1: snprintf (snprintf.c:33)
==5272==    by 0x400C9E: main (111.c:32)
==5272==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==5272==    at 0x4E860B0: zmq::stream_engine_t::mechanism_ready() (stream_engine.cpp:793)
==5272== 
Identifier: de.logicway.pferdepflug
Message: testfahrt
==5272== 
==5272== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5272==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5272==   total heap usage: 210 allocs, 210 frees, 271,368 bytes allocated
==5272== 
==5272== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5272== 
==5272== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5272== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Uninitialized value originates in `stream_engine.cpp:793`, so this should be probably reported to [ZeroMQ bug tracker](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues).